# Attain many has-many-through

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I need to attain latest comments from **array** of users through posts.

**Users model**

```
public function comments()
 {
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Comment', 'App\Post');
 }
```

has-many-through

```
$user = users::where('id',5)->first();

$user->comments()->get()
```

many has-many-through

```
$user = users::where('role','member')->get();
```

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You might looking for the method with() in ORM to get your expected results.

eg. `User::where('field','SOMECONDTION')->with('comments');

so in your foreach on your view you simply get the comments data.

```
@foreach($users as $index => $user)
   @foreach($user->comments as $j => $comment)
       {{$comment->some_field}}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: But I need the overall 10 latest comments for the group of users, This gives me individual comments for each user, Is there any way without loop, It will slowdown the performance. Thank You.

Comment: You may want to consider using 'View' table in database with your corresponding conditions and then create a model for that 'View' so you can still use the ORM feature of laravel.